# SEO and asynchronous page load

Tags: php, javascript, seo, usability, sitemap

To load page elements asynchronously I use jquery load() and it greatly improves user experience. But the crowlers do not know anything about javascript, so site ranking should drop. To prevent it I created sitemap page. I do not see other solution.

The bad thing is that url is different. Normal page is page.html and sitemap's one is page2.html. This means that crowlers will have page2.html indexed. So, users would come to page2.html. But if they start browsing the site they'll come to nice pages with asynchronous load.

Yet, I am not absolutely sure that I have chosen good strategy. Can anybody say what seo problems can happen?

UPD: I've got solution! I simply try to place a cookie with javascript and if on next page load php scripts finds it, then it performs asynchronous load. Here's example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.cookie = 'checkjs=on';</script>
```

And then:

```
if (!$_COOKIE['checkjs'] || $_COOKIE['checkjs']!='on'){echo 'js is off, hello Google!'; } else {echo 'js is on, can use jquery load';}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's bad solution - if you have important async load ( eg. page content - your case ) you must make sure that client withut javascript can get anywhere on your site ( this is done automatically by most MVC frameworks ).

Note 1 - any ajax page changes must be done via a onclick attribute ( so if javascript is off, classic href will do the trick )

Note 2 - if anyone don't opens main page ( page.html ) - he must get same layout as if he clicked thru your site there

Comment: I cannot imagine visitor with js turned off. Have a look at Ticket master [link](http://www.ticketmaster.com). Without js you cannot browse nor order tickets. Even here there're a lot of functionality depends on js. I am also aware of how ajax links should be made, but I have onload event, not onclik. And certainly the design is the same.

Comment: i not said visitor,  but client ( meaning - network client eg. google, your browser etc. ) - without JS client may see all important informations, but it is ok, when client without JS cannot do all things on your web ( eg. for ordering ticket JS is required, but for listing is not required - it is good for crawlers )

Answer (score 0):

If content is only made available through JavaScript then it is not search engine friendly. It also isn't accessible which is not a coincidence. To properly display that content so everyone can find the content you need to make it all work without JavaScript *then* go back and use JavaScript to enhance the user experience. This is called progressive enhancement and is the proper way to build a public-facing website.